# How to tag particles in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, tagging, particles, binning

I have a spherical configuration of particles whose positions are recorded in a 'dump file', these particles then change positions and the new coordinates recorded in another dump file. I am binning the particles in radial strips but I also need to tag them so that I know where each particle was previously.

I have n particles and my particle x, y, z positions are stored in the array `xyz` (respectively, `xyz(1,n)`, `xyz(2,n)`, `xyz(3,n)`).

My code looks something like this:

```
! Set bins

rbins = 0.0
dr = rs/float(nbins)
do i=1,nbins
  rbins(i) = float(i)*dr
enddo

! Binning data

do i=1,n
  r = sqrt(dot_product(xyz(1:3,i),xyz(1:3,i))) ! radial positions
  ii = int((r-rbins(1))/dr + 1) ! bins
  if (ii > nbins) cycle
enddo

! Writing data to file

open(iunit,file=fileout)

do i=1,nbins
  write(iunit,'(6(1pe18.10,1x))') r !,etc.
enddo

close(iunit)
```

How would I tag the particles so that I could compare their old and new radial positions?

Comment: What is a particle (in the code)? Do you use derived types? I don't understand your code. What is `rbins`? What does the code sample do? How does your file writing code look like?

Comment: @VladimirF just think of them as test particles which have x, y, z positions that are stored in those arrays, `rbins` is just the radius of each of the strips/bins. I am binning the data and then writing the radial positions to a file. What are derived types?

Comment: How are you writing the data to a file? Please show the code or the file structure.

Comment: @VladimirF they're in the do loop where I calculate the radial positions using the x, y, z positions: `r = sqrt(dot_product(xyz(1:3,i),xyz(1:3,i))) ! radial positions`

Comment: I have found them now, I was looking for a code and they were bold text instead. I changed them to code.

Comment: Sow are you just storing the radial positions or what are you storing? Can't you just have one additional array `tag(i)`?

Comment: @VladimirF yes I need to store the radial positions so that I can compare them from the two different files. I am reading the arrays `xyz(:,n)` from the dump files. What would `tag(i)` do?

Comment: So if you have `n` particles, why can't you compare the particle radius computed from `xyz(:,i)`  to a more update version of  `xyz(:,i)`? Isn't the second dimension of this array actually a tag for the particles?

Comment: @b-fg the thing is, the size of array `xyz(:,n)` isn't necessarily the same from one dump file to the next, that is, n may be lower (some particles are lost), so I need to have a way to keep track of which particle is which, does that make sense?

Comment: Okay, this was not mentioned. Then what I would do is to create a derived type `particle` which contains `tag` and `position` and work with that. If you do not know what a derived type is (from you previous comment) do some research as it will be useful for this problem and in the future as well (hint: it is just an object, as you would call it in c++).

Comment: @b-fg thanks for the advice, will look into it.

Comment: @b-fg I wouldn't recommend moving to derived types. The program now uses (structures of) arrays and that is fine, than can be kept https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOS_and_SOA